# sql trigger daterange with weekdays

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tabels on MSSQL(2012) DB ("tblA" and "tblB"). After insert on "tblA" I want a trigger to autogenerate on "tblB" the records with dates between the STARTDATE and ENDDATE from "tblA" but only on the weekdays selected on "tblA"

for example on "tblA":

```
tblA_ID: 99
CAT: TEXT1
STARTDATE: 01/01/2015
ENDDATE: 31/01/2015
MONDAY: true
TUESDAY: false
WEDNESDAY: false
THURSDAY: false
FRIDAY: true
SATURDAY: false
SUNDAY: false
```

"tblB" should get

```
 1   99    TEXT1   02/01/2015 (=Friday)
 2   99    TEXT1   04/01/2015 (=Monday)
 3   99    TEXT1   09/01/2015 (=Friday)
 4   99    TEXT1   11/01/2015 (=Monday)
 5   99    TEXT1   16/01/2015 (=Friday)
 6   99    TEXT1   28/01/2015 (=Monday)
 7   99    TEXT1   23/01/2015 (=Friday)
 8   99    TEXT1   25/01/2015 (=Monday)
 9   99    TEXT1   30/01/2015 (=Friday)




    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblA]
(
    [tblA_ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [tblA_CAT] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [tblA_STARTDATE] DATE NULL, 
    [tblA_ENDDATE] DATE NULL, 
    [tblA_MONDAY] BIT NULL, 
    [tblA_TUESDAY] BIT NULL, 
    [tblA_WEDNESDAY] BIT NULL, 
    [tblA_THURSDAY] BIT NULL, 
    [tblA_FRIDAY] BIT NULL, 
    [tblA_SATURDAY] BIT NULL, 
    [tblA_SUNDAY] BIT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblA] PRIMARY KEY ([tblA_ID]), 
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblB]
(
    [tblB_ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [tblA_ID] INT NOT NULL,
    [tblB_CAT] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [tblB_DATE] DATE NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblB] PRIMARY KEY ([tblB_ID]), 
)
```

Comment: Which dbms? (Most dbms products have their own implementations of triggers... and date/time...)

Comment: using **MSSQL 2012**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trigger should work for you. It uses a recursive common table expression to generate all the `tblB_DATE` values in the range and then a case expression to test if the name of the day is in those flagged as true. Note that this part depends on the system language so if you're not using English you have to adjust the date name literals according to your specific language.

The recursive common table expression serves as a substitute for a calendar table, so if you have an appropriate table that can act as a source for dates then you can use that instead (it should give better performance).

Please also know that the code lacks error checking and hasn't been optimized and thus probably can be improved. It should give you an idea about how you can solve your problem.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_tblb ON [dbo].[tblA] AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

    WITH dates AS (
       SELECT 
          tblA_ID, tbla_CAT, tbla_STARTDATE, tbla_ENDDATE, 
          tbla_MONDAY, tbla_TUESDAY, tbla_WEDNESDAY, tbla_THURSDAY, 
          tbla_FRIDAY, tbla_SATURDAY, tbla_SUNDAY,
          tblA_STARTDATE tblB_DATE
       FROM inserted
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT tblA_ID, tbla_CAT, tbla_STARTDATE, tbla_ENDDATE, 
          tbla_MONDAY, tbla_TUESDAY, tbla_WEDNESDAY, tbla_THURSDAY, 
          tbla_FRIDAY, tbla_SATURDAY, tbla_SUNDAY,
          DATEADD(DAY, 1, tblB_DATE) tblB_DATE
       FROM dates 
       WHERE dates.tblB_DATE <= tblA_ENDDATE
    ) 

    INSERT tblB (tblA_ID, tblB_CAT, tblB_DATE)
    SELECT tblA_ID, tblA_CAT, tblB_DATE
    FROM dates
    WHERE DATENAME(DW,tblB_DATE) IN (
       CASE WHEN tblA_MONDAY = 1 
          THEN N'Monday' END,
       CASE WHEN tblA_TUESDAY = 1 
          THEN N'Tuesday' END,
       CASE WHEN tblA_WEDNESDAY = 1 
          THEN N'Wednesday' END,
       CASE WHEN tblA_THURSDAY = 1 
          THEN N'Thursday' END,
       CASE WHEN tblA_FRIDAY = 1 
          THEN N'Friday' END,
       CASE WHEN tblA_SATURDAY = 1 
          THEN N'Saturday' END,
       CASE WHEN tblA_SUNDAY = 1 
          THEN N'Sunday' END
    )

    ORDER BY tblA_ID, tblB_DATE
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
END
```

Comment: thats **amazing**. I was looking for that a month.  Can I ask how to do if the diff between Startdate and enddate is bigger the 30days. For example:        tblA_ID: 99
    CAT: TEXT1
    STARTDATE: 01/01/2015
    ENDDATE: 31/12/2015
    MONDAY: true
    TUESDAY: false
    WEDNESDAY: false
   THURSDAY: false
    FRIDAY: true
    SATURDAY: false
    SUNDAY: false

Comment: @RMU I'll change it to handle longer ranges; I thought it did, but I guess I didn't test it enough.

Comment: @RMU I changed how the code works and replaced the values construct with a recursive cte instead. It should work as you want now.

Comment: thats it!  **1000 thks**